# How to correctly receive postMessage events from a Streamlit iframe in a Next.js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, iframe, streamlit

I'm integrating a Streamlit app within a Next.js application by embedding the Streamlit in an iframe. My objective is to send data from the Streamlit app to the Next.js parent using `window.postMessage`, specifically to transmit "total tokens used" information. However, I'm encountering difficulties in capturing these messages within the Next.js app.

**Problem:**

Despite setting up an event listener in my Next.js app to listen for `message` events, and sending a message from the Streamlit app using `postMessage`, the messages do not seem to be received by the Next.js app. The event listener I've added does not appear to trigger upon sending the message.

**Next.js Parent Code:**

```
// Inside a React component
useEffect(() => {
  const handleMessage = (event) => {
    console.log('Received message:', event.data);
  };

  window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);

  // Cleanup to remove event listener
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
  };
}, []);
```

**Streamlit Child Code:**

```py
# Python snippet to send message to parent
js = """
<script>
window.parent.postMessage({totalTokensUsed: 1234}, '*');
</script>
"""
st.components.v1.html(js, height=0)
```

**What I've Tried:**

1. Ensuring both apps (Streamlit and Next.js) are up and accessible.
2. Using the wildcard '*' for the target origin in the `postMessage` call for debugging purposes.
3. Adding console logs within the message event listener to check if it's being executed, which it doesn't seem to be.
4. Used window.parent.socket.postMessage... (as in [postMessage not being received from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33630495/postmessage-not-being-received-from-iframe))
5. Read [postMessage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

**Questions:**

1. Are there any known compatibility issues with `postMessage` communication between Streamlit iframes and a Next.js parent application?
2. How should the `postMessage` call and the event listener be structured to work with Streamlit's execution model?
3. Could CORS policies be impacting the message delivery, even when using '*' as the target origin?

Comment: Does it work if you put the listener in the root of your app, rather than a React component?

Comment: Thanks a lot David! I am using the app router in Next.js. As far as i understand it is not possible to use clientside functions and interactions in the root/app route. Therefore i would have to do it in the component where the client side is handled. Correct me if i misunderstood you.

Comment: You could put it in the Next start up code or separately on the page outside of Next

Comment: I was not able to put it in the start up code or outside of Next. I always got problems because it is a client interaction. Thanks a lot for checking in an giving hints @DavidBradshaw! I really appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if you are accessing the correct parent. If you aren't receiving message on the first level parent by posting it on `window.parent`.

Try

`window.parent.parent.postMessage`

Comment: This was it! Thanks a ton Nikhil! This was an absolute lifesaver!